# gnuplot reseting terminal to default output

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot, using the commands

```
set term pdf
set out 'filename.pdf'
plot sin(x)
```

allows me to write the image to a pdf.  After doing so, how do I reset the output so that `plot sin(x)` creates the image using the built-in gnuplot display (as it does without ever have using `set out` in the first place).

Right now I can only acheive this by restarting gnuplot.  The `reset` command does not seem to help.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have the X11 version of gnuplot installed. Set the terminal back to x11 and reset the output

```
set term x11
set out
```

Comment: Thanks parkydr.  It turns out my default terminal is `wxt`, so for me this is achieved by `set term wxt`.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to the other answer, you could do:

```
set term pop
set output   #reset standard output stream
```

In general, you can save the terminal settings you're currently working one using:

```
set term ... #what you want to save
set term push
set term ... #temporary terminal
set term pop #restore the terminal settings that you "pushed"
```

However, as documented in `help set terminal`:

> The command `set term push` remembers the current terminal including its
>    settings while `set term pop` restores it. This is equivalent to `save term`
>    and `load term`, but without accessing the filesystem. Therefore they can be
>    used to achieve platform independent restoring of the terminal after printing,
>    for instance. **After gnuplot's startup, the default terminal or that from
>    `startup` file is pushed automatically.** Therefore portable scripts can rely
>    that `set term pop` restores the default terminal on a given platform unless
>    another terminal has been pushed explicitly.